# $2^{49}$ ways to choose a set of integers $\leq 50$ with odd sum

Tags: combinatorics

> Show that the number of ways one can choose a set of distinct positive integers, each smaller than or equal to $50$, such that their sum is odd, is $2^{49}$.

**My attempt:** Suppose set $A=\{1,2,3,...,50\}$. I need to find the number of subsets $S\subset A$ where sum of elements of $S$ is odd. There are a total $2^{50}$ subsets of $A$, including empty subset $\phi$ (with sum of elements $=0$). How can I prove that exactly half of these subsets have sum of their elements odd?

Comment: Hint:  either add or remove the number $1$ to any subset to correct the parity of the sum.

Comment: Great @lulu ! I also came up with another solution myself, turns out its a rather easy problem..

Comment: Your answer looks perfect.  You can accept it (and thereby close the question).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sum of the elements of $A \text{ is }1+2+...+50 = 1275$, an odd number. Thus if I split $A$ into two subsets, one of them will always have odd sum, and the other one even!

[Sorry for answering my own question, I just came up with this after posting the question]

Answer (score -1):

$A=(1,2,・・・,50)=(1,2,1,2,・・・,1,2)$ $mod 2$

First 1 or 0 changes even or odd.Next 2 or 0 doesn't changes.・・・ so problem is even if all are odd numbers$(1,3,5,・・・49),$ their sum is $2^{n-1}$

Comment: Serial voting come. help.

Comment: This is a well deserved downvote.  The answer is completely incomprehensible.